# Возможно ли прикрепить скриншот страницы к каждому "then" степу (pytest-bdd, selenium, allure)

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, allure

Я пишу тесты на pytest-bdd + selenium + allure. И столкнулся с необходимостью делать скрин страницы на каждый шаг проверки. В pytest-bdd есть хук "after step" и в моем варианте он выглядит так:

```
def pytest_bdd_after_step(request, feature, scenario, step, step_func, step_func_args):
    if step.keyword == 'Then':
        driver = request.getfixturevalue('driver')
        allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name='screenshot',
                      attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```

Это работает, но скрины крепятся в репорте не к конкретному шагу. а после всех шагов:

[image: Allure report: screenshots appeared after all steps]

Собственно, вопрос в следующем: существует ли возможность прикрепить скриншот к степу "then" в хуке "after"?
Спасибо!

Comment: Hello! Please translate your question to Russian. Its Russian version of stackoverflow.

Comment: Сделал. Перепутал ру и англ. версии Стека...

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, это единственный возможный подход: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728908/is-it-possible-to-have-screenshots-of-allure-report-between-steps-like-extent-re

Тема может быть закрыта...